# Can we claim that all the terms in a matrix are less than equal to 1 if spectral radius is less than 1?

Tags: matrices, sp.spectral-theory, eigenvalues

I have a a full column rank matrix A, and using this I want to construct a matrix with spectral radius less than 1. I do that using,

H = $I-\alpha A^{T} A$ ($I$ is identity matrix), where the term $\alpha$ is defined as, $0<\alpha < \frac{2}{trace(A^{T} A)}$.

Can I claim that each one of therm in my matrix H will be less than or equal to 1?

I believe that the solution is yes, since I have not been able to come up with the a single scenario where this claim is not true. But I am not able to prove this.

Comment: No I mean how can I prove that the values in H are bounded by 1?

Comment: Sorry, I misread the question.  I have deleted my comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Your matrix $H$ is symmetric, so the spectral radius is the same as the maximal eigenvalue is the same as the maximal singular value. From the singular value description, for any unit vectors $\vec{u}$ and $\vec{v}$, we deduce that $|\vec{u}^T H \vec{v}| < 1$. Taking $\vec{u}$ and $\vec{v}$ to be the $i$-th and $j$-th basis vector, we have $|H_{ij}| < 1$.

Comment: To say it another way, for a symmetric matrix, the spectral radius equals the operator norm.  And by Cauchy-Schwarz $|u^T H v| \le |u| |Hv| \le |u| |v| \|H\|$.  Then take $u,v$ to be unit basis vectors.

Comment: @RohitShukla : but when the matrix is not symmetric, it is not true anymore, take $M = \left(\begin{array}{ll}1&2000000\\0&0\end{array}\right)$ whose eigenvalues are $1$ and $0$, hence its spectral radius is $1$ ...